# Dimension of Latent Heat

Tags: dimensional-analysis

Recently I read in my physics book, that the dimension of Latent heat is $[L^2 T^{-2}]$

But, I think that the dimension of Latent heat should be $[M L^2 T^{-2}]$, as latent heat is the amount of heat lost or gained by a body during the change of phase, without any rise in temperature.

The dimension given in my book suits well with **specific latent heat**, i.e. the amount of heat energy lost or gained by a body, per unit mass, during the change of phase without any rise in temperature.

Which concept is correct?
I'm confused.
Any clarification will help a lot. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

"Which concept is correct?" is the wrong question to ask. Both heat and specific heat are used depending on whether you want to emphasize the mass involved or not.

Comment: Okay. Then my direct question is, which is the correct dimensional formula for latent heat? The one given in the book or which I think is correct?

Comment: It is quite obvious looking at the dimensions that the book is referring to specific latent heat (an intensive property) since there is no massive dimension involved.

Comment: Yeah. But in the book, it's written as the dimensional formula of latent heat. According to my knowledge, the word "specific" is very much important here. Right? Might be a printing mistake?

Comment: You can safely assume at your level that whenever the word "specific" is involved, the mass has been divided out. For example, c.f. heat capacity vs. specific heat capacity.

Comment: Yeah. I think it might be just a printing mistake to print the dimensional formula of"specific latent heat" in the row of "latent heat". Or it might be that the "specific" word was missed out in the name of the physical quantity. What do you think?

Comment: I don't know what book you are using. Sometimes books might use the two terms interchangeably, but I might use a better book to be sure I am learning the right things.

Comment: Yeah. You are pretty much right. Even Google ignores the word "specific" and when you search for the formula of latent heat, you get the formula of specific latent heat. Anyways, thanks for the reply.